# is there a way to cross-platform encrypt a drive, so my disk works across macOS and Linux?

Tags: dell, encryption, macosx, crossplatform

I've been working on an SNES-Styled RPG video game project for the past 2 years now, and shortly after I purchased my first flagship laptop, an i7 Dell Inspiron 7570 currently running Ubuntu 19.04 with a Samsung EVO 860 SSD, despite being an absolute speed demon at what I do with it, I realized that the battery is pretty terrible, and it's not very travel friendly. So, I reluctantly made the investment of a MacBook Air as a travel machine. **Big mistake**, but I also needed GarageBand, so it's not a total loss. However I realized that now, I have no way to encrypt my external drives across platforms! this is an issue because I sometimes take a shuttle, so if my drive ever gets lost or stolen, I'm kind of screwed. I'm considering on buying a tertiary machine, possibly an XPS 13, or just a simple entry-level 13/14-inch machine, but for the time being, is there a way I can cross-encrypt my drives, so this isn't an issue for me?

P.S. As for data recovery, that's not an issue. I bought a brand new SanDisk drive solely for the purpose of working on-the-go.

P.P.S. Does anybody know if the Samsung T5 SSD encryption software works on Linux systems, and if this is actual encryption and not just password protection? I highly doubt it works with Linux, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

```
Samsung encryption example seen on the T5's commercial: https://youtu.be/-9So6n85_tg?t=32
```

Comment: Is this an external drive you're looking to encrypt?

Comment: Yes it is. I don't have much else to say but I'm required to have at least 15 characters before I'm allowed to add any comments, so that's what this extra sentence is for.

Comment: If you want it for an external drive I would suggest to do this the hardware way. Startech USB 3.0 encrypted 2.5 SATA HDD is pretty popular overhere. 99 euro. Found an english version: https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-encrypted-SATA-drive-enclosure-Black/dp/B00TR8V32U

Comment: What about https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html ?

Comment: @mook765 that's what I was going to suggest.